# CA trusted cert on AKS management API

Tags: azure-aks

My company uses Cisco Umbrella to block certain websites and traffic. When using kubectl to connect to my AKS cluster, there is an error saying the root CA is not trusted. When trying with "--certificate-authority", and passing in the Umbrella CA certificate, there is an error saying Umbrella will not trust the connection. The same error with "--insecure-skip-tls-verify".

I believe Umbrella is blocking self signed certificates or anything untrusted.

Is there a way to configure an AKS cluster to use an external well known CA certificate for the management API?